# Checkbox value only when checked

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox

I'm trying to get the checkbox output to a variable x only when checked. Now it passes the value of checkbox even unchecked

```
 function myFunction(){
        
     var  x  =parseInt(document.getElementById('cough').value)+
     parseInt(document.getElementById('cold').value)+ 
     parseInt(document.getElementById('fever').value) + 
     parseInt(document.getElementById('breathlessness').value) +
     parseInt(document.getElementById('loss of senses').value) + 
     parseInt(document.getElementById('sore throat').value) +
     parseInt(document.getElementById('none').value) +
     parseInt(document.getElementById('diabeties').value)+
     parseInt(document.getElementById('heart disorder').value) +
     parseInt(document.getElementById('lung disorder').value)+
     parseInt(document.getElementById('kidney disorder').value) + 
     parseInt(document.getElementById('hypertension').value) + 
     parseInt(document.getElementById('no disorder').value);
        
          console.log(x)
    }
```

I need to get these values only when checked

Comment: I'm new to JS so could you please elaborate or provide an example

Comment: Actually, don't store your data in the markup, [use a "model" instead](https://jsfiddle.net/ber3hdvn/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need the `checked`-property of a checkbox. So, you could use something like

```
// ...
(document.getElementById('hypertension').checked ? 
 parseInt(document.getElementById('hypertension').value) : 0) + 
(document.getElementById('heart disorder') ? 
 parseInt(document.getElementById('heart disorder').value) : 0)
// ...
```

That will become bulky quite fast. Here's a bit of checkbox magic you may want to study

Lookups:

- [Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)
- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
document.addEventListener("change", checkTheBoxes);

function checkTheBoxes(evt) {
  if (evt.target.type && evt.target.type === "checkbox") {
    console.clear();
    // handle 'none'
    if (evt.target.checked && +evt.target.value < 1) {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")
          .forEach(v => v.checked = +v.value > 0 ? false : v.checked);
    } else {
      document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox'][value='0']").checked = false;
    }
    
    // filter checked checkboxes
    const values = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")]
      .filter(v => v.checked);
    
    if (values.length) {
      console.log( `total ${values.reduce( (a, v) => a + +v.value, 0)}` );
      //                                                 ^ use + to convert to Number
    } else {
      console.log( "no values checked (yet)");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> cough
<input type="checkbox" value="2"> cold
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> fever
<input type="checkbox" value="4"> breathlessnes
<input type="checkbox" value="0"> none
```